# instantiation of nested template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, nested

I have a class as shown below:

```
template <class T>
class outer {
public:
  typedef T TType;
  std::vector <TType> v;
  int f1 (TType t) {cout << "t= " << t << endl;};

  class inner {
  public:
    inner& operator=(const inner &in) {return *this;}
    void f2(const inner &in) {cout << "in f2\n";}    
  };
  inner read() {cout << "in read\n";return inner();}
};
```

Outer has to have nested `inner`. I have to create a Base class for `outer` (We are going backwards here !!). I should be able to derive `outer1` from the Base. Existing clients of `outer` should work without changing anything. `outer` should just add code to derive from the base class.

My solution to this is:

```
template <typename T>
class outer_iface {
public:  
  typedef T TType;
  std::vector <TType> v;
  virtual int f1(TType t) {cout << "bt= " << t << endl;}; 

  template <typename U>
  class inner_iface {
  public:
    using value_type = U;
    inner_iface& operator=(const inner_iface &in)
    {
      return static_cast <U*> (this)->operator=(in);
    }
    void f2(const inner_iface &in)
    {
      return static_cast <U*> (this)->f2(in);
    }
  }; //inner_biface

  /*template <typename U>
  typename inner_iface <U>::value_type read()
  {
    return static_cast <U*> (this)->read();
  }*/
};

template <typename T>
class outer : public outer_iface  <T> {
public:
  typedef T TType;
  std::vector <TType> v;
  int f1 (TType t) {cout << "t= " << t << endl;};

  class inner : public outer_iface <T> :: template inner_iface <inner>  {
   public:
     inner& operator=(const inner &in) {return *this;}
     void f2(const inner &in) {cout << "in f2\n";}    
 };
 inner read() {cout << "in read\n";return inner();}
};
```

This compiles and builds. But, I have 2 questions:

1. is my declaration/definition of `read` correct in `outer_iface`?
2. how can I instantiate an `outer_iface`, with say `int` type, and call `read` ?
3. I tried from `main()`:

   ```
   outer_iface<int> oi;
   oi.read();
   ```

clang gave errors:

```
g++ -g --std=c++11 test7.cpp
test7.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test7.cpp:62:11: error: no matching function for call to       
‘outer_iface<int>::read()’oi.read();
                                  ^
test7.cpp:62:11: note: candidate is:
test7.cpp:28:40: note: template<class U> typename      
outer_iface<T>::inner_iface<U>::value_type outer_iface<T>::read() 
[with U = U; T = int]
typename inner_iface <U>::value_type read()
                                ^
test7.cpp:28:40: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test7.cpp:62:11: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘U’
oi.read();
```

So, obviously I don't have it right. How can I fix `inner_face::read` ?
Any help/insight is appreciated.
thanks
sdp

Comment: What is "outer1"? *Please* don't use extremely confusing names like "verylongname" and "very1ongname" and "veryIongname1". Can we please just have "Foo" and "Bar"?

Comment: Why introduce CRTP for `inner` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want something like:

```
template <typename T>
class outer_iface {
public:  
    // ...

    typename T::inner read()
    {
        // std::cout << "in read\n"; return typename T::inner();
        return static_cast<T*>(this)->read();
    }
};
```

Comment: Jarod42, to test your suggestion I added a class `Foo::inner_face, and in main do outer_face <Foo> oi. This gives an error: g++ -g --std=c++11 test7.cpp
test7.cpp: In instantiation of ‘typename T::inner_iface outer_iface<T>::read() [with T = Foo; typename T::inner_iface = Foo::inner_iface]’:
test7.cpp:75:11:   required from here
test7.cpp:34:33: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘outer_iface<Foo>* const’ to type ‘Foo*’
   return static_cast <T*> (this)->read() `

Comment: @sdp: oups, misread, though that `T` were CRTP as for inner... Can you add template argument to `outer_iface` to get `outer` and so `outer::inner` ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really understand. The issue is the declaration of `outer_iface::read()` which should return an `inner_iface`. If you could give a snippet it would help me in understanding.

Comment: if `outer_iface::read()` returns `inner_iface`. `outer::read` would be completly unrelated... Not sure what you expect we your base class in your scenario...

Comment: ok, I see. So the only thing I want to do now is to have `outer_iface::read()` return a `inner_iface` type. Also, how should `outer_iface` and `inner_iface` be instantiated in `main`.  the code `template <typename U>
  typename inner_iface <U>::value_type read(){}` compiles, but I am not able to figure out a way of instantiating so that the fn gets called. As you pointed out the base class is unrelated to the derived. But I should be able to test the base class on its own. Right?

Comment: In `template <typename U> typename inner_iface <U>::value_type read(){}`, `U` cannot be deduced. you have to specify it in call site like `oi.read<outer::inner>()`.

Comment: suppose I have only the `outer_face` as I have shown, and `outer_face::read` has to return an `inner_face` object. So, `template <typename U> inner_face<U>::read() { how should I return inner_face;}`. My understanding of templates is basic. I have read the standard books on templates, but did not find my answer. Is what I am trying to do even possible?